# Oracle SQL where clause subquery not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a car rent management database and I created a query which should output car maintainer supervisors that have more than 1 subordinates (maintainers). In my case only one supervisor has 2 subordinates.

When I try to use this select statement, it still outputs all supervisors, when in reality I only need to output the first row. Would really appreciate your help, I am quite new in SQL and this is for my school project.

```
  1  select s.name || ' ' || s.surname as "Supervisor", s.mobile_nr as "Telephone", count(w.id_worker) as "Total subworkers"
  2  from supervisor s, worker w, maintainer m
  3  where s.id_supervisor=w.id_supervisor and w.id_maintainer=m.id_maintainer and (select count(id_worker) from worker, maintainer where maintainer.id_maintainer=worker.id_maintainer)>1
  4* group by s.name, s.surname, s.mobile_nr
SQL> /

Supervisor                                                    Telephone            Total subworkers                                         
------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------------                                         
Marcis Janeks                                                 +37122176223                        2                                         
Ilona Katlina                                                 +37128632447                        1                                         
Skaidris Kalnins                                              +37123389601                        1                                         
Zane Masta                                                    +37126874141                        1                                         
Karlis Maiznieks                                              +37128610671                        1                                         
Modris Upmalis                                                +37125012112                        1                                         
Ilgonis Smaidins                                              +37129636642                        1                                         
Janis Kurpnieks                                               +37126178482                        1                                         
Vladimir Kurcavenko                                           +79061177915                        1                                         
Miraldas Hakomas                                              +37022892633                        1                                         

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HAVING` clause rather than an (uncorrelated) sub-query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(s.name || ' ' || s.surname) as "Supervisor",
       MAX(s.mobile_nr) as "Telephone",
       COUNT(w.id_worker) as "Total subworkers"
FROM   supervisor s
       INNER JOIN worker w
       ON s.id_supervisor=w.id_supervisor
       INNER JOIN maintainer m
       ON w.id_maintainer=m.id_maintainer
GROUP BY s.id_supervisor
HAVING COUNT(w.id_worker) > 1
```

*Note: you probably want to `GROUP BY` the primary key for the supervisor rather than using the name as there could be two people with the same name (and the same phone number if they shared an office).*

*Note 2: Use the ISO/ANSI standard join syntax rather than the legacy comma-join syntax from 30 years ago that is difficult to read.*